# Sending email with inline images Flask-Mail?

Tags: python-3.x, email, flask

I have an application that uses `Flask` and `Flask-Mail`. I am trying to send an email that uses an html file as a template with inline images. Everything is working except I can not see the images. My code is:

```
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    msg.attachments = [
        Attachment(
            'header.gif',
            'image/gif',
            open(join(mail_blueprint.static_folder, 'header.gif'), 'rb').read(),
            'inline'
        )
    ]
    mail.send(msg)
```

for the html file I have tried referencing it a couple ways, like:

`<img src="cid:footer.gif">` and
`<img src="{{ url_for('mail.static', filename='header.gif') }} ">`

Any references or ideas why these wouldn't work?

Comment: HTML templates (and embedded `url_for`) are only rendered when the [render_template is called](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

Answer (score 9):

You need to add a 'Content-ID' header value in your attachment.

```
msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
msg.body = text_body
msg.html = html_body
msg.attach('header.gif','image/gif',open(join(mail_blueprint.static_folder, 'header.gif'), 'rb').read(), 'inline', headers=[['Content-ID','<Myimage>'],])
mail.send(msg)
```

Then in your template you will refer to the attachment via the Content-ID.

```
<img src="cid:Myimage">
```

Comment: `headers=[['Content-ID','<Myimage>'],]` should be a dict - `headers={'Content-ID': '<MyImage>'}`.

Comment: I don't know why my flask-mail is 0.9.1 and the code is not fixed [fix headers for attachments](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/commit/e195fca6de1077cabb711426e6378f51dc39d598)  but you can see the source code to choose the correct way.